# Reactjs max-width of an Input from props (using Styled components)

Tags: reactjs, antd, styled-components

I have an input (antd) which is styled using styled components. The issue is I can't update the max-width of it using props.this is the code

```
 const TextInput = styled(Input)`
  border: 2px solid #edf4ff;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: ${(props) => props.width};
  max-width: ${(props) => props.maxWidth};
  min-width: ${(props) => props.minWidth};
  height: 64px;
  background-color: ${(props) => props.backgroundColor};
  &:active,
  &:focus,
  &:-internal-autofill-selected {
    background-color: white !important;
    margin-left: 17px;
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass maxWidth as prop to styled TextInput

```
<TextInput maxWidth={'500px'}>ABC</TextInput>
```

Comment: that is what I am trying but it changes nothing